# ERROR: Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\User\OneDrive\Desktop\Slush\index.js'

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio

I was writing a code in VSC using nodejs and while running the nodemon, I encountered the following error: [The Terminal Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RV48z.png)[package.json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwFBk.png)[index.js (I did put in the key while of the bot while executing)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Laa0w.png)

Please suggest what can be done so that nodemon runs well...

Comment: Well, does the file `C:\Users\shyam\OneDrive\Desktop\Slush\index.js` exist? Because your `package.json` suggests you put it inside `src` folder.

Comment: That is the problem here
I did put it in the src folder but it still doesn't reflect the "\src" in the location of the file.
But the file C:\Users\shyam\OneDrive\Desktop\Slush\index.js does not exist.